# AWS Glue Crawler creates each tables for each parquet data

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-glue

In the glue job, I created dynamic_frame from AWS RDS PSQL using glue connection and write the data into S3 after doing some ETL jobs. After that, I created and run Glue Crawler for the parquet file wrote in S3. Here is the sample code.

```
     dynamic_frame = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options('postgresql',
                                                                         connection_options)


    glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
         frame=cleaned_dynamic_frame,
         connection_type="s3",
         connection_options={"path": export_path},
         format="parquet")



   response = glue.create_crawler(
        Name=crawler_name,
        Role=role,
        DatabaseName=db_name,
        Targets={
            'S3Targets': [
                {
                    'Path': path
                }
            ]
        },
        TablePrefix='{}_'.format(table_name)
    )


### S3 Objects list in the path (20 parquet files)
<bucket>/<path>/part-0000-a.snappy.parquet
<bucket>/<path>/part-0001-b.snappy.parquet
<bucket>/<path>/part-0002-c.snappy.parquet
<bucket>/<path>/part-0003-d.snappy.parquet
<bucket>/<path>/part-0004-e.snappy.parquet
<bucket>/<path>/part-0005-f.snappy.parquet
<bucket>/<path>/part-0006-g.snappy.parquet
<bucket>/<path>/part-0007-h.snappy.parquet
<bucket>/<path>/part-0008-i.snappy.parquet
```

Problems: 
The glue crawler supposed to create one Table with the same schema for those parquet data. However, somehow glue crawler created multiple tables for each parquet data and each table's location is for each parquet data. Not Combined. This happens sometime.. some times work correctly...

My guess is that spark creates _temporary file to s3 before it finish glue job... and at the moment where the temp file exists, glue crawler is running and it creates each table for each file.

Please comment below if you have any sense what is going on.
Thank you for your great help.

Comment: Did you try to add exclude patterns to skip temp files to be crawled? Besides that try to set option 'Create a single schema for each S3 path' to true (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/crawler-configuration.html).

Comment: Appreciate your helps! I added s3.waiter to check _temporary folder is gone. adding exclude pattern is also great solution. Thanks again.

Comment: hey @hyeonggunlee, I'm facing the same problem. Which action solved the problem for you?

Comment: @DaniloGomes Hi, firstly I added custom waiter to wait until the _temporary folder does not exist in the s3 path. However, this could not solve the problem perfectly. So I added exclude pattern for the _temporary folder in the glue crawler. Now It seems like working!  Here is the exclusion pattern for the crawler 
                        'Exclusions': [
                            '*_temporary**'
                        ]

Comment: * _temporary **

Comment: @hyeonggunlee I gave * _temporary ** as my exclude pattern, but still, it is creating a separate table for each partition. Any thoughts?